# Gerenciar corretamente as conexões com o banco de dados usando o hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Qual seria o melhor padrão para as conexões, pensei em dois modos :

Modo 1 :

Cada função cria e fecha sua própria conexão

Função 'inserir'

```
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Tarefa");
        EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.persist(t);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
        manager.close();
        factory.close();
```

Modo 2:

Uma conexão static para a classe, caso a conexão esteja fechada, um método é usado para abrir.

```
private static EntityManagerFactory factoryClasse = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Tarefa");
private static EntityManager managerClasse = factoryClasse.createEntityManager();

private static void conectar()
{
    factoryClasse = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Tarefa");
    managerClasse = factoryClasse.createEntityManager();
}

public static Boolean inserir(Tarefa t)
{
    try
    {
        if(managerClasse.isOpen() == false || factoryClasse.isOpen() == false)
            conectar();
        managerClasse.getTransaction().begin();
        managerClasse.persist(t);
        managerClasse.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Em termos de velocidade e/ou segurança qual a mais adequada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso vai depender da aplicação: se ela suportará um usuário ou múltiplos usuários simultaneamente; se ela vai utilizar uma ou múltiplas *threads*; da arquitetura da aplicação; se será utilizado algum *framework* que gerenciará transações e injetará o `EntityManager`, etc.

Para você identificar qual solução adotar, é importante que você entenda as principais classes da JPA: `EntityManagerFactory` e `EntityManager`.

### EntityManagerFactory

Um `EntityManagerFactory` é uma classe imutável e *thread safe* que representa o mapeamento do modelo de domínio para com o banco de dados. Ele mantém todos os serviços utilizados pela implementação JPA utilizada, como *cache* de segundo nível, *connection pool*, etc. A sua criação é extremamente onerosa, por isso, deve ser criado uma única vez para cada banco de dados utilizado pela aplicação.

### EntityManager

Um `EntityManager`, por sua vez, não é *thread safe*, portanto deve ser utilizado por uma única *thread* por vez. Ele gerencia o ciclo de vida dos objetos que fazem parte do seu contexto através de um *cache* de primeiro nível. Ao contrário do `EntityManagerFactory`, o `EntityManager` é um objeto de vida curta e barato de ser criado.

É importante ressaltar que o `EntityManagerFactory` e o `EntityManager` **não** representam uma conexão com o banco de dados, eles **utilizam** conexões. A forma que a conexão é obtido e quando isso ocorre fica a cargo da implementação JPA. Já o gerenciamento dessas conexões fica a cargo do *connection pool* (não é recomendado o uso *connection pool* padrão utilizado pelo Hibernate em produção. Deve-se utilizar bibliotecas específicas como DBCP e c3p0).

O Hibernate, por exemplo, obtém a conexão de um *connection pool* apenas quando o primeiro *SQL statement* é executado, e, dependendo do `release_mode` utilizado, a conexão será liberada após a execução do *SQL statement* (`after_statement`) ou quando ocorrer um *commit* ou *rollback* (`after_transaction`).

Com isso em mente, podemos avaliar suas duas soluções.

### #1

Como vimos, a criação de um `EntityManagerFactory` é uma operação extremamente onerosa. Sendo assim, criar tal objeto toda vez que for necessário executar um método, além de desnecessário, pode trazer sérios problemas de performance, o que torna tal implementação inviável.

### #2

Como vimos, um `EntityManager` **não** é *thread safe*, logo, mantê-lo como uma variável estática que pode ser utilizada por diversas *threads*, é algo perigoso.

Além disso, você está vinculando sua transação a operação de inserir. Como você faria caso fosse necessário inserir múltiplos registros em uma única transação? Implementaria outro método que recebesse várias tarefas? E se fosse necessário que uma transação modificasse múltiplos tipos de objetos (talvez interagir com múltiplos *DAOs*, caso você utilize esse padrão), implementaria um método que recebesse todos eles? Tal solução poderia ser viável em pequenas aplicações, mas em aplicações maiores, isso poderia gerar problemas. Além disso, existiria um repetição enorme de código para gerenciar as transações.

### Uma possível solução:

Com todos esses problemas em mente, podemos começar a vislumbrar uma solução.

#### Criar uma classe responsável por gerenciar as transações:

*Transactional*:

```
/**
 * 
 * Representa operação que deve ser realizada de forma atômica.
 *
 * @param <T> retorno da transação, caso haja um
 */
public interface Transactional<T> {

    public T execute();
}
```

*TransactionManager*:

```
/**
 *  Gerencia as transações
 *
 */
public interface TransactionManager {

    public <T> T doInTransaction(Transactional<T> transaction);
}
```

*JPATransactionManager*:

```
/**
 *  Implementação de um gerenciador de transações para a Java Persistence API
 *
 */
public final class JPATransactionManager implements TransactionManager {

    private final EntityManagerFactory emf;

    private final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal;

    public JPATransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf, ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal) {
        this.emf = emf;
        this.threadLocal = threadLocal;
    }

    @Override
    public final <T> T doInTransaction(Transactional<T> transaction) {
        EntityManager em = null;
        T result = null; 
        try {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            threadLocal.set(em);

            em.getTransaction().begin();

            result =  transaction.execute();

            em.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch(RuntimeException e) {
            if(em != null && em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                em.getTransaction().rollback();
            }
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if(em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
            threadLocal.remove();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

#### Exemplos de entidades:

*Person*:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Car> cars;

    protected Person() {}

    public Person(int id, Set<Car> cars) {
        this.id = id;
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Person))
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", cars=" + cars + "]";
    }
}
```

*Car*:

```
@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String model;

    protected Car() {}

    public Car(int id, String model) {
        this.id = id;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Car))
            return false;
        Car other = (Car) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car [id=" + id + ", model=" + model + "]";
    }
}
```

#### DAOs

*PersonDAO*:

```
public interface PersonDAO {
    public void save(Person person);
    public List<Person> getAll();
}
```

*JPAPersonDAO*:

```
public final class JPAPersonDAO implements PersonDAO {

    private final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal;

    public JPAPersonDAO(ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal) {
        this.threadLocal = threadLocal;
    }

    public final void save(Person pessoa) {
        getEntityManager().persist(pessoa);
    }

    public final List<Person> getAll() {
        return getEntityManager()
                .createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p", Person.class)
                .getResultList();
    }

    private final EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        EntityManager em = threadLocal.get();
        if(em == null || !em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            throw new TransactionRequiredException();
        }
        return em;
    }
}
```

*CarDAO*:

```
public interface CarDAO {
    public void save(Car car);
}
```

*JPACarDAO*:

```
public class JPACarDAO implements CarDAO {

    private final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal;

    public JPACarDAO(ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal) {
        this.threadLocal = threadLocal;
    }

    @Override
    public final void save(Car car) {
        getEntityManager().persist(car);
    }

    private final EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        EntityManager em = threadLocal.get();
        if(em == null || !em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            throw new TransactionRequiredException();
        }
        return em;
    }
}
```

#### Por fim, exemplos desse modelo funcionando em ambientes com uma única *thread* e em ambientes com múltiplas *threads*:

Uma *thread*:

```
public class SingleThreadPersistenceJPA {

    private static final List<String> CAR_MODELS = Arrays.asList(
            "Gol", "Siena", "Civic", "Celta", "Sandero", "Tucson"
    );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
        try {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("seu-persistence-context");
            final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();
            final TransactionManager tm = new JPATransactionManager(emf, threadLocal);

            final PersonDAO personDao = new JPAPersonDAO(threadLocal);
            final CarDAO carDao = new JPACarDAO(threadLocal);

            tm.doInTransaction(() -> {
                Car car1 = new Car(1, CAR_MODELS.get(0));
                carDao.save(car1);
                Car car2 = new Car(2, CAR_MODELS.get(3));
                carDao.save(car2);

                Set<Car> cars = Stream.of(car1, car2).collect(Collectors.toSet());
                Person person1 = new Person(1, cars);
                personDao.save(person1);


                Car car3 = new Car(3, CAR_MODELS.get(1));
                carDao.save(car3);
                Car car4 = new Car(4, CAR_MODELS.get(2));
                carDao.save(car4);

                cars = Stream.of(car3, car4).collect(Collectors.toSet());
                Person person2 = new Person(2, cars);
                personDao.save(person2);

                return null;
            });

            tm.doInTransaction(personDao::getAll).forEach(System.out::println);

        } finally {
            if(emf != null && emf.isOpen()) {
                emf.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

E em Ambiente com múltiplas *threads*:

```
public class MultipleThreadPersistenceThread {
    private static final List<String> CAR_MODELS = Arrays.asList(
            "Gol", "Siena", "Civic", "Celta", "Sandero", "Tucson"
    );

    private static final AtomicInteger PERSON_ID = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static final AtomicInteger CAR_ID = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
        try {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("seu-persistence-context");
            final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();
            final TransactionManager tm = new JPATransactionManager(emf, threadLocal);

            final PersonDAO personDao = new JPAPersonDAO(threadLocal);
            final CarDAO carDao = new JPACarDAO(threadLocal);

            ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
            final Random random = new Random();

            for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                es.submit(() -> {
                    tm.doInTransaction(() -> {
                        Car car1 = new Car(CAR_ID.incrementAndGet(), CAR_MODELS.get(random.nextInt(CAR_MODELS.size() - 1)));
                        Car car2 = new Car(CAR_ID.incrementAndGet(), CAR_MODELS.get(random.nextInt(CAR_MODELS.size() - 1)));
                        carDao.save(car1);
                        carDao.save(car2);

                        Set<Car> cars = Stream.of(car1, car2).collect(Collectors.toSet());
                        Person person = new Person(PERSON_ID.incrementAndGet(), cars);
                        System.out.println("Saving person: " + person.getId());
                        personDao.save(person);
                        return null;
                    });
                });
            }

            es.shutdown();
            while(!es.isTerminated()) {}

            tm.doInTransaction(personDao::getAll).forEach(System.out::println);

        } finally {
            if(emf != null && emf.isOpen()) {
                emf.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Para se aprofundar:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#architecture-overview

https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-aggressive-connection-release/

Comment: Incrível solução..